# Change in Angular momentum of a spinning superball

Tags: experimental-physics, conservation-laws

I throw a [superball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Ball) towards the ground and when I do I intentional induce a spin on the ball so that the ball is spinning towards me on the descent.  As soon as the ball hits the ground and comes back up, the direction of the spin has changed and its spinning away from me.  I assume this tied directly to a conservation law but I am curious if anyone can give and explicit discussion as to the effect.

Comment: Additional discussion can be found in this [paper](http://personal.maths.surrey.ac.uk/st/P.Aston/Papers/bouncing_ball1.pdf) which discusses how the effects of colliding with the ground serve to shift the direction of spin